# If I use TypeScript to create ES5 script, do I need a traceur script tag in my html?

Tags: typescript, angular, traceur, systemjs

I am using TypeScript 1.5 to generate ES5 script for a simple angular2 app.

Will I need to include both a script element referencing a module loader (such as SystemJS) AND a script element referencing traceur (such as the one below) in my index.html file?

```
<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.91/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
```

...Or do I only need the script element for SystemJS?

Comment: I haven't kept up, but it appears you still need it. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3694) as they still use some traceur polyfills. However, you might get away without it depending on what you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I know traceur still is a dependency of angular2. There's an issue to remove it though, therefore in the future it'll be possible. [Here you can find the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3694) for it if you want to track the progress.